# Separate ansible provisioning playbooks in vagrant

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm using vagrant and ansible to provision a virtual machine and that works fine. The ansible playbook clones a git repo, installs it and runs a service daemon.

I'd also like to have a vagrant command that executes a separate "update" playbook that pulls the latest from the git repo, installs and restarts the daemon.

Something like this usage would be nice.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  # Default
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
  end

  # Update
  config.vm.provision "ansible", name="update" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "update.yml"
  end
end
```

Then I could run it with `vagrant --provision-with update`. Is something like this possible? I'd like to avoid having to ssh into the box to run an update like this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure why the person's answer was deleted because it was correct. As of vagrant 1.7.0 you can [name provisions](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html).

The following worked:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  # Default
  config.vm.provision "main", type: "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
  end

  # Update
  config.vm.provision "update", type: "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "update.yml"
  end
end
```

You can use `vagrant provision --provision-with <foo>` to then execute either one.

However, if you do `vagrant up`, all provisioners will run, which is not desired. As a solution, I run `vagrant up --no-provision` then `vagrant provision --provision-with main` as the default, which I put in a Makefile.